# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in nodejs and reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I try posting the token gotten from my registration via the code below, but I get the error, maximum call stack exceeded

```
exports.activationController = (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.body;

  exports.activationController = (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.body;

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          errors: 'Expired link. Signup again'
        });
      } else {
        const { name, email, password } = jwt.decode(token);

        const user = new User({
          name,
          email,
          password
        });

        user.save((err, user) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json({
              errors: 'User cannot be saved.'
            });
          } else {
            return res.json({
              success: true,
              message: 'Signup success'
            });
          }
        });
      } 
    });
  } else {
    return res.json({
      message: 'Please try again.'
    });
  }
};
```

I have done the registration like this

```
exports.registerController = (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      const firstError = errors.array().map(error => error.msg)[0];
      return res.status(422).json({
        errors: firstError
      });
    } else {
      User.findOne({
        email
      }).exec((err, user) => {
        if (user) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            errors: 'Email is taken'
          });
        }
      });

      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
          name,
          email,
          password
        },
        process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION,
        {
          expiresIn: '5m'
        }
      );

      const emailData = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        to: email,
        subject: 'Account activation link',
        html: `
                  <h1>Please use the following to activate your account</h1>
                  <button style="padding: 15px; background-color: blue; text-align:center; opacity: 0.2; outline: none; border-radius: 10px;"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: white;" href="${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/users/activate/${token}">Activate your account</a></button>
                  <hr />
                  <p>This email may containe sensetive information</p>
                  <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}</p>
              `
      };
```

I get the error "maximum call stack exceeded" when posting the activation" by using postman. I really do not know where in my code, this error is coming from

This is the response

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>     at
> RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
>     at
> _pathToPositionalSyntax (C:\Users\User\Documents\My projects\greenlifeapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:854:16)
>    at Schema.pathType (C:\Users\User\Documents\My
> projects\greenlifeapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:1200:21)
>    at model.$set (C:\Users\User\Documents\My
> projects\greenlifeapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1160:33)
>    at model.set [as password] (C:\Users\User\Documents\My
> projects\greenlifeapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\document\compile.js:174:19)
>    at model.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\My
> projects\greenlifeapp\models\auth.model.js:34:19)
>     at
> VirtualType.applySetters (C:\Users\User\Documents\My
> projects\greenlifeapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\virtualtype.js:167:16)
>    at model.$set (C:\Users\User\Documents\My
> projects\greenlifeapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1264:12)
>    at model.set [as password] (C:\Users\User\Documents\My
> projects\greenlifeapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\document\compile.js:174:19)
>    at model.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\My
> projects\greenlifeapp\models\auth.model.js:34:19)

The mongoose model where I have defined the user

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    }, 
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true     
    }, 
    hashed_password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    salt: String,
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Normal'
    },
    resetPasswordLink: {
        data: String,
        default: ''
    }
}, {timeStamp: true})

// Virtual password
userSchema.virtual('password')
.set(function(password){
    this.password = password
    this.salt = this.makeSalt()
    this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password)
})
.get(function(){
    return this._password
})

// Methods
userSchema.methods = {
    // Generate salt
    makeSalt: function(){
        return Math.round(new Date().valueOf() * Math.random()) + ''
    },
    // Encrypt Password
    encryptPassword: function(password){
        if(!password) return ''
        try{
            return crypto
            .createHmac('sha1', this.salt)
            .update(password)
            .digest('hex')
        } catch (err) {
            return ''
        }
    },
    authenticate: function (plainPassword) {
        return this.encryptPassword(plainPassword) === this.hashed_password
    }
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

Comment: Provide error stack trace to help others to figure out where the error occurs. Currently it's near to impossible to tell what's going on.

Comment: Happens when your recursive functions take too long to run, use an iterative approach.

Comment: Can you also share the mongoose model where `User` is defined? The stack trace points to a problematic (recursive?) regular expression, perhaps for validating the `email`?

Answer (score 0):

All operations related to database like find,save,findOne are asynchronous in nature. To execute that you should either use promise or async/await. For ex. to save the user you should use this

```
exports.activationController = async (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.body;

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          errors: 'Expired link. Signup again'
        });
      } else {
        const { name, email, password } = jwt.decode(token);

        const user = new User({
          name,
          email,
          password
        });

        await user.save((err, user) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json({
              errors: 'User cannot be saved.'
            });
          } else {
            return res.json({
              success: true,
              message: 'Signup success'
            });
          }
        });
      } 
    });
  } else {
    return res.json({
      message: 'Please try again.'
    });
  }
};
```

and for registration like this

```
exports.registerController = async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
   // if validationResult is async function use await here as well
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      const firstError = errors.array().map(error => error.msg)[0];
      return res.status(422).json({
        errors: firstError
      });
    } else {
      await User.findOne({
        email
      }).exec((err, user) => {
        if (user) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            errors: 'Email is taken'
          });
        }
      });

      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
          name,
          email,
          password
        },
        process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION,
        {
          expiresIn: '5m'
        }
      );

      const emailData = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        to: email,
        subject: 'Account activation link',
        html: `
                  <h1>Please use the following to activate your account</h1>
                  <button style="padding: 15px; background-color: blue; text-align:center; opacity: 0.2; outline: none; border-radius: 10px;"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: white;" href="${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/users/activate/${token}">Activate your account</a></button>
                  <hr />
                  <p>This email may containe sensetive information</p>
                  <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}</p>
              `
      };
```

Let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: It didn't :( I tried the possible, but it still didnt work

Comment: Can you share your code repo. I need to know the filenames to decode the error.